# I am having problems in booting up my Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2, initramfs

I use a Dell Vostro with an Intel i3 processor. It already had Ubuntu installed, and is the only OS on the laptop (no Windows or anything). Today I tried rebooting and it showed the Grub coding. I figured it out and now it showing and error with initramfs : **Unable to find a medium containing a live file system, [the image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c8xp.jpg)**.  Mind you, Ubuntu is the only OS so I haven't connected any USBs or got it from ISO.

When I further searched for a solution, I saw notes on usage of fsck but I am getting the message that the function does not exist.

What shall I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am a novice myself, but during my installation I had a problem that I couldn't access the system. (I simply messed fstab up).
I used the installation USB stick and used the "Try Ubuntu" option.
I mounted the system disk (using Disks) and used the Terminal to correct the fstab. Fdisk is available on the installation usb.

I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: How do you use the terminal in this situation?

Comment: With the installation USB you can start up your system.
Start Terminal (Command prompt) via the application menu or Control Alt T
Type `sudo -s` for super user 
You can now use `fsck` as you found on the web.
- Disk to check should not be mounted
- So for example you can use `fsck /dev/sda1 -c` or to repair any errors on your disk you can use `fsck -c -y /dev/sda`  or to check all your unmounted disks `fsck -AR -y`